# Event added using content provider isn't saved

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentresolver, android-calendar

I tried adding a calendar event to the Android calendar using this code:

```kotlin
fun insertEvent(event: CalendarEvent): Uri? {
    val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, event.startTimeStamp)
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, event.endTimeStamp)
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, event.title)
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, event.location)
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, event.calendarId)
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, event.timeZone.id)
        
    return contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values)
}
```

When I use it, I get a URI returned but cannot see it in a calendar app like Google Calendar or aCalendar. Using the debugger verified that the `contentValues` all had the correct data.

My app requests these permissions:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
```

They are enabled in app info.

Comment: Perhaps those calendar apps do not use the OS calendar database, but instead use [Google Calendar's own hosted data store](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/java). Or, perhaps there is some delay in your changes being synced to some master data store. FWIW, I usually use `ACTION_INSERT` so the user controls the calendar app, I don't need permission, the user can amend the information, and it doesn't matter where/how the data gets stored.

Comment: I think they do store their data in androids calendar db since all local calendars I created usin aCalendar appear in my app when I query them with a ContentResolver. These local calendars are being found by Google Calendar as well.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was, that I used unix-Timestamps instead of milliseconds, so the events were to old for Android.